# Design of a 5kW residential Solar system with battery- need help with electrcial diagram

Tags: energy, electrical, solar-energy, diagram

A design project asks for a design proposal of 5kW solar panel with inverter and battery system for a residential house.

I have completed the energy estimation, panel size, orientation, and selected suitable solar inverter (SMA Sunny Boy 5kW) and battery (Tesla Powerwall 7kWh)

The question asks to provide an electrical wiring diagram of the system-

1. Single-phase with earth and neutral connection
2. Switchboard layout of generation and storage
3. At least one of the loads is more than 5kw

I know how to design the diagram for parts 1 and 2 but could not understand how to approach part 3.

Should I show the connection of all residential loads?

Comment: No, you would show the outputs as far as the circuit breakers and their labels (Lighting 1, Water Heater, etc.).

Comment: If you are to design a 5kW power system with multiple output loads and one of the loads is over 5kW you are no longer designing a 5kW system. (Perhaps you should be designing a 7kW system?)

Comment: @Nedd I was thinking the same, but clearly the instruction said 5kW PV for a house of 4.

Comment: @NJah - Ahhhh, you didn't actually include "5kW PV" in the description.  The PV part of the system is 5kW by design, but the rating of the complete system is what ever the total of all the loads amount to.

Comment: The inverter needs to be rated for the peak load, not the peak power of the array.